# Angular2 SharedModule vs Service

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a service that handles all API calls of USER (insert, delete, update, lookup).

The first thing on my mind is to create a `SharedService` (UserService), that will handle al HTTP calls for the user API.

However, this can also be implemented as a `SharedModule` in Angular2. 
What is a best practice in this case?

Comment: It *is* a service, it could be *in* a module.

Answer (score 0):

Shared service is a better practice since as per convention services contain specific business logic for an operation without any additional unrelated code to the business logic.

Modules on the other hand in angular js is a container which encapsulates other services, controllers etc. Hence injecting an entire module just to invoke a service is not warranted given that a module contains much more than the service and these extra components would unnecessarily make your controller heavy.

Always while injecting try to inject the resource which is focused on solving the problem you want to solve without it bringing too many extra components.

Comment: In this case - Should a User Service be included inside a Module to make it singleton?

Comment: Ideally yes, service should be singleton with no state information